# Redirect users based on if they are signed in or not in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I want to set a root_path for my rails app where I want root to be devise/sessions#new if user is not signed in
and home#index if user is signed in

obviously i can't use user_signed_in? method in routes so how may I achieve it ?
also how can I make devise/sessions#new my root path ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You can do something like this in your application_controller.rb`:</strike>

```
devise_for :users

devise_scope :user do
   authenticated :user do
   root 'home#index', as: :authenticated_root
  end

  unauthenticated do
   root 'devise/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
  end
end
```

**Update:**

In your `application_controller.rb`:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
 # your_path
end
```

Comment: This give me the error of could not find mapping for devise '/'

Comment: @AlaapDhall Updated my answer hope it helps now If not then let me know

Comment: This is the error message I got .. and i have everything in scope although m not sure with that bypassing the router thing

Comment: ok so now it says that cannot find root_path in my controller did you mean fint_path?

Comment: @AlaapDhall Sorry its taking to long! If you are using Devise 4 than  Try my updated answer this will probably solve the issue remove `devise_scope` from routes and try the application controller solution

Comment: @AlaapDhall Have this solved your issue If yes than mark it as accepted so that this Question will be removed from Unsolved Questions. If not than let me know the issue.

Comment: It didn;t work for me but may be it will for someone else.. so m making it acceptable. I figured another way by redirecting users from within cintroller instead of routes.  Thank you neway

Comment: I tested How to redirect that and than I have updated my answer as you can see how to redirect it from the controller rather than from routes Hope it helps other But it's working for me on rails 5 and rails 4 with devise 4.2

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do   
  devise_for :users

  unauthenticated do
    root to: 'home#index', as: 'unauthenticated'
  end

  authenticated :user do
    root to: 'sessions#new', as: 'authenticated'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not very elegant but you can just edit your home#index controler

def index
if user_signed_in? 
 ...your code
else
redirect_to new_user_session_path
end
end